# Extracting XML inner node elements in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML document that looks like this:

```xml
<root>
  <key>
    <id>v1</id>
    <val>v2</val>
    <iv>v3</iv>
  </key>
</root>
```

How do I extract the `v2` values and `v3` values of a `key` node using its `v1` value in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like using [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) for processing XML:

```
var xml = XElement.Parse(@"<root>
                             <key>
                               <id>v1</id>
                               <val>v2</val>
                               <iv>v3</iv>
                             </key>
                           </root>");

var key = xml.Elements("key").First(x => x.Element("id").Value == "v1");

Console.WriteLine("val: " + key.Element("val").Value);
Console.WriteLine(" iv: " + key.Element("iv").Value);
```

I have ignored all error checking for brevity.

For example *[First()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535050%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)* would throw an exception if the element is not found. You might want to use *[FirstOrDefault()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549039%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)* and check for *null* if you are expecting that or handle edge cases a bit more gracefully.

Same goes for *[Element()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)* calls. They might return *null* so calling *.Value* could result in a *System.NullReferenceException*. To avoid clutter I usually use extension methods to do these checks:

```
static class XElementUtilities
{
    public static string GetValue(this XElement xml, string name)
    {
        var element = xml.Element(name);
        return element == null ? null : element.Value;
    }

    public static bool ValueEqual(this XElement xml, string name, string value)
    {
        var element = xml.Element(name);
        return element != null && value != null && element.Value == value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `First()` instead of `FirstOrDefault()` will cause this code to crash if there is not a match.

Comment: @CamBruce good point. I just wanted to demonstrate the solution in a concise fashion. Error checking and other niceness are left for the reader to decide.

Answer (score 3):

Use Linq.

```
 var myXml = XDocument.Parse("<root>
                                <key>
                                <id>v1</id>
                                <val>v2</val>
                                <iv>v3</iv>
                                </key>
                            </root>").Root.Elements("key")
                        .FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Element("id").Value == value);

    if (myXml  != null)
    { 
     var myObject = new 
        { 
          id = myXml.Element("id").Value, 
          val = myXml.Element("val").Value,
          iv = myXml.Element("iv").Value 
        });
    }
```

Of course, you need to check for missing elements, etc, if required.

Comment: This doesn't work. Element() doesn't return IEnumerable you need Elements(), and myXml won't be an IEnumerable either, so Select won't work either.

Comment: wrote the answer too fast - it's fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Use xpath:

```
/root/key[id='v1']/val
/root/key[id='v1']/iv
```

so something like

```
myXmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/root/key[id='v1']/val").Value
myXmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/root/key[id='v1']/iv").Value
```